# Waiting for GNU Parallel processes to finish when using & and spawning via Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pipe, gnu-parallel

In my current application, I have a Python 2.7 script called `main.py` that launches another Python 2.7 script called `calculator.py` using GNU Parallel like the following:

```
os.system("seq 10000 | parallel -N0 -j 50 nohup python calculator.py &")
print "Done"
```

This works pretty well, with one exception: I need to resume executing other commands in `main.py` (that is, after the `os.system` call, e.g. the `print "Done"` line) just after all the 10000 instances spawned with GNU Parallel finish running.

Is there a proper way to do that? Solutions with `os.spawn` and Python 2.7 `subprocess` are both welcome, but using GNU Parallel is **absolutely mandatory**.

EDIT: Here are my requirements:

1) it is crucial to me that the many instances of calculator.py that are spawned keep running if the terminal closes (hence the nohup)

2) I need it to not block current terminal session (hence the &)

3) I need it to print "Done" in the example above gets executed only after the 10000 jobs finish

If achieving all above at the same time is not possible, I think I could then manually keep a log of all launched processes and then manually force the rest of the code "main.py" code to continue after all those processes end. This, of course, is a cumbersome last-resource option.

Comment: Could you just eliminate the `&` character at the end of your command?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I wish I could. That is the source of the whole challenge, since it does work as intended without the `&`

Comment: So you can't change anything inside the `"` symbols?

Comment: You can try to get the pids and use the wait command. See this answer to underrstand what I mean: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340077/how-do-i-wait-for-a-background-process-to-complete#340086

Comment: @JohnAnderson I'm not sure about that. What changes do you have in mind? It is crucial to me that the many instances of `calculator.py` that are spawned keep running if the terminal closes (hence the `nohup`), do not block current terminal session (hence the `&`) and that `print "Done"` in the example above gets executed only after the 10000 jobs finish.

Comment: If you start a new thread, and launch your `os.system()` call from that thread (without the `&`), the current session will not be blocked. Then your `print "Done"` command (or anything else you want) will occur after the call completes.

Comment: Note that in my above comment, the 'print "Done"` needs to be the new thread also.

Comment: Can you append "wait"? `os.system("seq 10000 | parallel -N0 -j 50 nohup python calculator.py & wait")`

Comment: @OleTange I certainly can, but then it simply behaves as if I never included the `&` in the first place. That is, "Done" is indeed only printed in the end but now the terminal is blocked until completion. See my edits for better context.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. 2 says you do not want it to block, 3 says you want it to block until done. Maybe you can make an MCVE of `calculator.py` so it is more clear what your goal is?